# How to use setSelectionRange with document.getElementsByClassName?

Tags: javascript, jquery, copy, textarea, clipboard

How to use `SetSelectionRange` with `document.getElementsByClassName`? I can use `document.getElementById`, but why can't I use `document.getElementsByClassName`?

I want to copy the text from textarea. I need with class attribute.

JavaScript

```
$('.get_copy').on('click', function() {
    var copyText  = document.getElementsByClassName('textareaclass');
    copyText.select();
    var start     = copyText.selectionStart;
    var end       = copyText.selectionEnd;
    copyText.setSelectionRange(start, end);
    document.execCommand("copy");
});
```

HTML

```
<textarea class="textareaclass">SAMPLE TEXT</textarea><button class="get_copy"></button>
<textarea class="textareaclass">SAMPLE TEXT 2</textarea><button class="get_copy"></button>
```

Comment: Probably because `getElementById` returns a single element and `getElementsByClassName` returns a collection so you need to loop through them. If you'd like a definitive answer, please add the relevant code to the question

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: I added the code.

Comment: Thanks for editing, I added an answer for you below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because `getElementsByClassName()` returns a collection, not a single element.

From the context of the code it looks like you want to retrieve the `textarea` related to the clicked `button`. As you've already added jQuery to the page you can use `prev()` to do this. Alternatively you can use the native `previousElementSibling` property, however this is more brittle and easily broken.

```js
$('.get_copy').on('click', e => {
  var copyText = $(e.target).prev('textarea')[0]; // jQuery
  //var copyText = e.target.previousElementSibling; // plain JS
  
  copyText.select();
  var start = copyText.selectionStart;
  var end = copyText.selectionEnd;
  copyText.setSelectionRange(start, end);
  document.execCommand("copy");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea class="textareaclass">SAMPLE TEXT</textarea>
<button class="get_copy">Get copy</button>

<textarea class="textareaclass">SAMPLE TEXT 2</textarea>
<button class="get_copy">Get copy</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that [`getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) returns one element, since there can only be one of each ID. But [`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns a node list, since there can be many that use the same class. You can use `[index]` to get the appropriate element you want.

```js
const one = document.getElementById('one')
const all = document.getElementsByClassName('example')

console.log({one,all})

console.log('first is: ', all[0])
```

```html
<div id="one" class="example"></div>
<div id="two" class="example"></div>
```